# Catch out of bounds exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to objective C with previous knowledge of java. I am learning how the language works and I am wondering how to catch outOfBoundsExceptions in objective-c? Specifically with arrays.

Example:

```
NSString *stringReceivedServer=@"Jim 1551 error";
NSArray *split= [stringReceivedServer componentsSeparatedByString:""];
NSString *labelString= [split objectAtIndex:3] //Out of bounds
```

I did this example because I will be fetching some info from a server and I will be getting the info as showed above. There is a standard for how the data will be sent but sometimes things can go wrong so if the string isn't what it should be, how can I can catch the error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, don't rely on exception handling, instead just ***write correct code.***

Second, if you're interested: you can catch `NSException`s using the `@try-@catch-@finally` exception handlers:

```
@try {
    id obj = [array objectAtIndex:array.count]; // BOOM
}
@catch (NSException *e) {
    NSLog(@"Got ya! %@", e);
}
@finally {
    NSLog(@"Here do unconditional deinitialization");
}
```

Comment: +1 for saying **don't rely on exception handling, instead just write correct code**

Comment: Thanks! Why is it not recommended? Resource heavy?

Comment: @Teddy13 You're welcome. To quote myself: "Why make it fail then regret (i. e. throw and catch) if you can avoid exceptions at all?"

Comment: So should we say Java developers always regret? :D

Comment: @AnoopVaidya One thing is sure: I'd regret if I had to do Java. :P

Answer (score 5):

Unlike Java, since Obj-C is a superset of C, here out of bound is not an ERROR.

**It is logical error, you need to deal with your own logic.**

As,

```
NSString *labelString=nil;
if(split.count>3){
   labelString= [split objectAtIndex:3]; //Out of bounds
}
else{
    NSLog(@"out of bound");
}
```

Or you can do as:

```
@try {
   NSString *labelString = [split objectAtIndex:3];  
}
@catch (NSRangeEception * e) {
   NSLog(@"catching %@ reason %@", [e name], [e reason]);
}
@finally {
   //something that you want to do wether the exception is thrown or not.
}
```

Comment: But yes, it **is** an exception. `NSArray` throws an exception when accessed out of bounds.

Comment: @H2CO3: What about this try-catch-block. :p

Comment: That's perfect, I was going to suggest that as well :)

Comment: @H2CO3: while i was in between to google and type here, you commented. We dont have time, as giving answers here is a RACE.

Comment: LOL :D I knew about `@try-@catch`, so it was a bit easier for me :)

Comment: @H2CO3: In my 3 years of cocoa experince I never used try-catch. if-else workd fine for me/US.

Comment: Neither did I, I don't like exception-based programming. Why make it fail then regret (i. e. throw and catch) if you can avoid exceptions at all?

Comment: @H2CO3: And once it is thrown you cant go back, if there was a way to go back then every one would have used. I guess.